# Azure @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client 404 when trying to create access policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, azure-policy

I'm trying to create a teams meeting with @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client but first it say that i have to create an access policy for my app with powershell. OK so i'm getting my app id like so:

```
Get-AzureADApplication
```

It respond me :

```
     ObjectId                             AppId                                DisplayName
 --------                             -----                                -----------
 37de00f1-836c-4f51-8924-1b9b6c419dbc           f7b9f9d8-3507-46dc-a596-60f437dbab87               BC Teams
```

So i'm using this id

```
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppIds "f7b9f9d8-3507-46dc-a596-60f437dbab87" -Description "description here"
```

But a 404 error

```
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy : Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (404) Introuvable.
```

(that's in french and it just mean server return 404 not found)

I realy need help on this i have no clue on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade the ***`microsoft teams powershell module`*** to the latest using Update-Module

```
Update-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

and Connect-MicrosoftTeams with  Admin credential .

I tried doing the same and could execute command successfully

[image]

> Note:
>
> 1. Skype for Business Online administrators are responsible for
>    managing policies.
> 2. Skype for Business Online Admins can manage both Teams and Skype for
>    Business Online app policies through PowerShell.
> 3. Skype for Business Online Connector is currently part of the latest
>    Teams PowerShell module.

Reference : [microsoft-teams-access-policy-new-csapplicationaccesspolicy-returns-404-SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249596/microsoft-teams-access-policy-new-csapplicationaccesspolicy-returns-404)

Comment: It didn't work for me, my installation of MicrosoftTeams module is fresh and i also tryed in azure integrated terminal still have a 404.
I'm thinking about user right, but it shouldn't return a 404 

Comment: @mathieujanio - Could you please share your MicrosoftTeams module version and powershell version?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT


So for powershell: 5.1 

AzureAD : 2.0.2.140            
MicrosoftTeams: 4.4.1

Comment: We have tried below steps and it was working fine at our end.
1. Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
 $userCredential = Get-Credential
 Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential

2.New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Meeting-policy-dev -AppIds "xxxxx" -Description "Online meeting policy - contoso town"
 Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Meeting-policy-dev -Identity "xxxxx"