# Create Microsoft Teams online meetings via API

Tags: azure, microsoft-entra-id

I'm trying to create Microsoft Teams online meetings via API following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) doc.

I can reach Microsoft Graph API because I have done all the steps like creating an app on Microsoft Entra and I got Client Id, Tenant Id and Secret Id.

In fact, I have tried to call [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint with success, but for the online meetings endpoint I need to create an Access Policy like Microsoft wrote [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).
Unfortunately, when I run the `New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy` command it returns:

`VERBOSE: EnabledForFlight: False, AutoRestCommandInfo: False`
`New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

My command is this: `New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity "Microsoft_Graph_Access_Policy" -AppIds "myid" -Description "Microsoft_Graph_Access_Policy" -Verbose`

Where am I wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> To **resolve** the error, check the version of installed *MicrosoftTeams* PowerShell module and upgrade it to latest version.

You can find that module version details by running below PowerShell command:

```
 Get-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below script by connecting with **Administrator** account and got the **response** successfully:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity "Microsoft_Graph_Access_Policy" -AppIds "appId" -Description "Microsoft_Graph_Access_Policy"
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName "Microsoft_Graph_Access_Policy" -Global
```

**Response:**

[image]

In my case, I generated  **access token**  using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to make below POST request,  **online meeting**  created successfully like this:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/createOrGet
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2023-12-27T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2023-12-27T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Demo Online Meeting",
  "externalId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "participants": {
        "attendees": [
            {
                "identity": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                },
                "upn": "sri@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - Microsoft Teams access policy - New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy returns 404 - Stack Overflow by **Ansuman Bal**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249596/microsoft-teams-access-policy-new-csapplicationaccesspolicy-returns-404?rq=2)